# Sencha Touch 2: auto center item in list after scrolling

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to implement a carousel (or tabs with srcoll) in a similar fashion to the http://zite.com/ application. The main goal is to implement autocentered scrolling of closest to the center item after the scroll end.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any other way than calculating the center manually in the scroll end event and scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you want centered a `Ext.Carousel` into main `Ext.Panel` write something like this,

```
new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    ...
    layout: {
       type: 'vbox', 
       align: 'center', 
       pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [
       new Ext.Carousel({
          ...
       })
    ]
})
```

and have fun `Carousel` centered. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: It's for ST2, so `new Ext.Carousel` is not the proper way to create a Carousel. Use `Ext.create('Ext.Carousel',{...})` instead

Comment: thanks for your response, but I meant another auto centring. Check the zite application - it does a post scrolling to center in the tab bar.